# Channel binding in gRPC for .NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, grpc, tls1.3, grpc-dotnet

I would like to implement channel binding for a gRPC service to ensure the TLS stream is terminated by the expected entity. There appears to be zero material available on how to do this with gRPC for .NET.

How can I access TLS channel's data necessary for channel binding using gRPC for .NET?